# Checking if a file is in a given directory

Tags: go, pathname

I've got a situation where I'd like to check whether a particular path lands inside of a particular directory. My first instinct was to do something like

```
filepath.HasPrefix(filepath.Clean(path), dir)
```

but the procedure `filepath.HasPrefix` is [documented as existing for historic reasons only](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#HasPrefix). Am I going to get the same effect by using `strings.HasPrefix`, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: In addition to `Clean` consider `filepath.EvalSymlinks()` and `filepath.Abs()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not missing anything, look at the source:

```
// HasPrefix exists for historical compatibility and should not be used.
func HasPrefix(p, prefix string) bool {
    return strings.HasPrefix(p, prefix)
}
```

Just use `strings.HasPrefix(p, prefix)` directly.

Answer (score 2):

While you will get the same functionality with `strings.HasPrefix`, it doesn't work in general. `filepath.HasPrefix` is deprecated for a reason and it's approach should be considered deprecated too.

Consider `filename=/foo/bar` and `prefix=/fo`. This passes the `strings.HasPrefix` test but clearly `bar` is not in `/fo`.

The proper approach would compare each directory name holistically.

Answer (score 0):

In Go 1.4 method `filepath.HasPrefix` [actually calls](http://golang.org/src/path/filepath/path_unix.go?s=606:643#L13) `strings.HasPrefix` so the answer is yes.